# AngularJS Material and Toastr CSS not working together

Tags: css, angularjs, toastr, angular-material

I'm using [AngularJS Material](https://material.angularjs.org/#/) and [Toastr](https://github.com/CodeSeven/toastr).

I've used bower to install both. They are working together except that the styling of the toastr is being overridden. So when I try to use `toastr.warning(...)` I get

[image]

instead of getting something similar:

[image]

The generated HTML head is:

```
<!-- bower:css -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../bower_components/toastr/toastr.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../bower_components/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../bower_components/angular-material/angular-material.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../bower_components/materialize/bin/materialize.css">
<!-- endbower -->
```

It was working with Twitter [Bootstrap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bootstrap_%28front-end_framework%29) before I moved to use AngularJS Material and Materialize.

Comment: did you check that toastr css was included by bower ?

Comment: yes it was included, but before the angular material css

Comment: Could you include code?

Comment: added the head code... it was working with twitter bootstrap 3 before I move to use angular material & materialize

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the order of the `bower.json` file, so that `toastr.css` comes after `angular-material` and `materialize.css`.